# Servers for video streaming 720p

Tags: video-streaming

Brother wants to stream 720p games from his colleagues in real time on his own site. I do not want to archive recordings. I wanted to ask if there are any services / servers for streaming video?

Comment: Resource recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [Wowza media systems](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine). There are several options how to use it. Service on demand, using own servers, etc.